# How can I find a specific subnode in XML with jQuery selectors/filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this XML of game modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<gameType>
<easy>
    <numberOfLevels>2</numberOfLevels>
    <levelGroup id="1">
        <level id="1">[0]</level>
        <level id="2">[1]</level>
        <level id="3">[2,2]</level>
    </levelGroup>
    <levelGroup id="2">
        <level id="1">[0]</level>
        <level id="2">[1]</level>
        <level id="3">[3,2]</level>
    </levelGroup>
</easy>
<medium>
    <numberOfLevels>1</numberOfLevels>
    <levelGroup id="1">
        <level id="1">[0,2]</level>
        <level id="2">[1,4]</level>
        <level id="3">[2,5,6]</level>
    </levelGroup>
</medium>
```

What I want to do is get all levels for the appropriate game mode. For example:

```js
//we get the list of all games
var xmlDoc = $(xml);
//we get number of levels for the selected game mode, default gameMode = 'easy'
var games = xmlDoc.find(gameMode).find("numberOfLevels")[0].textContent;
//we select a game by choosing a random number
var selectedGameIndex = $.random(games);
//Here I want to filter out only the appropriate elements, eg, in the default
//game mode and with the selectedGameIndex set to '1', I want to return an
//array that contains only the values, 
//eg. var resultArray = [[0],[1]....[2,11,12]]; What I got is this:

var elements = sandbox.baseLib.$(gameMode + " > levelGroup[id='"
    + selectedGameIndex + "']", xmlDoc).children();
 var predefinedIndexSequence = elements.map(function() {
    return sandbox.baseLib.$(this).text();
}).get();

gameLength = gameSequence.size();
```

Edit: This is the correct code (at least for what I need it). The mistake was in trying to filter xmlDoc when I didn't actually need the result from the filter, I needed the array made from "elements" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abbreviate the last chunk of your code (from `var levelsArray` onward) by using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
return elementsArray.map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

...although I would call it `$elements` instead of `elementsArray` because it appears it's actually a jQuery object, not a true array. If I'm wrong and it's not a jQuery object, do this instead:

```
return $.map(elementsArray,function(el,i) {
    return el.textContent;
});
```

You can also replace `var games = xmlDoc.find(gameMode).find("numberOfLevels")[0].textContent` with `var games = xmlDoc.find(gameMode).find("numberOfLevels:eq(0)").text()`, although that's not much shorter, just more jQuery-like.

Comment: @Andrija It would help if you told us exactly what you expected to get at the end of all this.

Comment: I'm expecting an array of array with the values for the selected levelGroup. That array is contained in the "return returnElement;" step of edit 3 and it looks like this:  "[0],[1],[2,2]" or "[0],[1],[3,2]" if the gameMode is 'easy'

Comment: I've posted the solution, thank you for the assistance and pointing me into the right direction.